# Regex optional group with | at the beginning not working

Tags: java, regex

I can have two kind of imput strings:

1. `text1`
2. `text1|text2`

I want to print the output string: `text1-text2`

I have tried this:

```
System.out.println("A|B".replaceAll("(.+)\\|(.+)?",     "$1-$2")); // I expect A-B
System.out.println("A|" .replaceAll("(.+)\\|(.+)?",     "$1-$2")); // I expect A-
System.out.println("A"  .replaceAll("(.+)(\\|(.+))?",   "$1-$3")); // I expect A-
System.out.println("A|B".replaceAll("(.+)(\\|(.+))?",   "$1-$3")); // I expect A-B
```

With the following output:

```
A-B
A-
A-
A|B-
```

What I'm doing wrong in the last sentece ?

Comment: Why in the world would you use a RegEx for this?

Comment: The first half `(.+)` happily matches *everything*, since the second half is optional.

Comment: text1 and text2 can cointain non alphanumeric caracters but |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.+` captures *everything* but newlines. Since the second group is optional, it will capture `A|B`.

So `$1` will be `A|B`, while `$2` and `$3` will be empty.

You need to use

```
(.+?)(\\|(.+))?
```

In order to make it work. The `?` means *As few times as possible*.

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/udvehj)

Comment: "captures everything but newlines, '$2' and '$3' will be empty." Made  my day

Comment: The 2nd `?` is irrelevant

Answer (score 1):

How about `"A|B".replace('|', '-');` -- there's no reason to use a RegEx here.

Comment: It's not my real problem, I just need to understand it before applying more complex regex to my problem.